# Is there a relation between Ill-posed problems and Eigenvectors.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

One can easily explain an ill-posed problem with an equation AX=b. The following link is an good example:

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Ill-posed_problems

1) Can there be a class of ill-posed problems where the matrix A is Hermitian positive definite matrix?

As written in the link, Tikhonov regularization is an established way to make the problem well-posed and to find a solution.

2).  Can we convert the problem ill-poised to well posed by posing properties of  Eigenvectors of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If $A$ is Hermitian positive definite, then $Ax=b$ is not ill-posed, since the matrix $A$ is invertible. It could be ill-conditioned if the condition of $A$, i.e., the quotient of its largest and smallest eigenvalue, is large.

2) No. For Hermitian matrices, eigenvectors are orthogonal, which is kind of an ideal situation. Ill-posedness is connected to the absolute values of eigenvalues.

If $A$ is only semi-definite (not positive definite), then $Ax=b$ is ill-posed. Tikhonov regularization means solution of $(A+\epsilon I)x=b$, which shifts the eigenvalues of $A+\epsilon I$ into the positive reals.

Comment: This clarifies the role of eigenvalue. Is there any reason or concepts which says that eigenvectors are not useful?

Comment: Considering your 1). What if the eigenvalues are complex?