# Can we term it as topological-regulrization?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question is related to the question below:

[Is there a relation between Ill-posed problems and Eigenvectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293420/is-there-a-relation-between-ill-posed-problems-and-eigenvectors)

In the answer of the above question, it was shown that the ill-posed problem can be explained in  terms of eigenvalues. My question: Is there any such relation between ill-posed problem and eigenvectors? What I mean by properties is for example can we express the ill-posed problem in terms of angle between the eigenvectors? In case we define such a functional then can we term it as topological-interpolation/regularization? Or topological-interpolation/regularization has a complete different meaning and not relevant here.